# odata getting property value from child collection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Let's suppose I have the following models:

```
public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter the authors based on criteria to return only those authors whose books cost more than 100 altogether.

```
http://localhost:9500/Author?$filter=Book/any(b: aggregate(b/Price) gt 100)
```

I have no idea how to create a query for such scenario.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking for the right HTTP URL, or how to implement in asp.net?

Comment: @ChrisNeve I'm referring to HTTP URL.

Comment: How about something like this? /Author?$apply=aggregate(Price with sum as TotalPriceForThisAuthor)&$filter=TotalPriceForThisAuthor gt 100

Comment: I'm not 100% on this one. Let me know if it seems to work, and if so I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: How can you expect this to work if Book was not mentioned in the query?

Comment: Maybe /Author?$apply=aggregate(Book/Price with sum as TotalPriceForThisAuthor)&$filter=TotalPriceForThisAuthor gt 100 then? I'm guessing at this point; I can't seem to find anything of interest in the documentation. I'll play around with it when I have time. Until then, probably your best bet is to make a service operation. See http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/